# Ffmpeg FLV compatibility with audio codecs

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to convert mp4 video to flv using ffmpeg with aac and mp3 codecs and get this error:

```
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+30-ba5684e3bx265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 11.2.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bitx265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-4.1 (High tier)x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 16 threadsx265 [info]: Slices                              : 1x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 4 / wpp(17 rows)x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intrax265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00 x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / onx265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-35000 kbps / 0.60x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvpx265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=6 deblock sao[flv @ 000002477811e9c0] Video codec hevc not compatible with flvCould not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implementedError initializing output stream 0:0 -- encoded 0 frames
```

I'm using ffmpeg version: `ffmpeg version 2022-02-14-git-59c647bcf3-full_build-www.gyan.dev`
on Windows 10.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

FLV is a proprietary format by Adobe. It does not support HEVC a.k.a. H.265.

Use H.264, i.e. `-c:v libx264`.